# ESXi + pfSense - NAT forward management interface ssh

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, esxi, pfsense

*question at the end.*

**Situation: *(ips replaced by fictive examples)***
I have a (remote) dedicated server, with 1 NIC, 2 IPs.
One IP (eg. 5.9.1.1) is bound to the physical NIC's MAC, the other (5.9.100.1) is assigned to a 'random' MAC.
No port filtering or NAT is present on remote network level.

**ESXi (v5.5) security profile**
Firewall is enabled.
All incoming connections *except* SSH, DHCP client, DNS client are restricted to 127.0.0.1-access only.
All outgoing connections *except* DHCP client, httpClient and DNS client are restricted to 127.0.0.1-access.
SSH-server service is enabled, with authorized key access only (no interactive login).

**vSwitch0 (named WAN):**

- Bound to physical adapter vmnic0
- VMKernel port for management network (gets the 5.9.1.1 IP)
- Virtual machine port for pfSense (gets the 5.9.100.1, by overriding its MAC)

**vSwitch1 (named LAN):**

- No physical adapter
- Virtual machine port for pfSense (IP set to 192.168.174.1 - DHCP enabled)
- Virtual machine port for Debian live cd (gets 192.168.174.10 from pfSense DHCP)
- Virtual machine port for Windows 2012R2 (gets 192.168.174.11 from pfSense DHCP)
- VMKernel port for management network (gets 192.168.174.12 from pfSense DHCP)

**pfSense configuration:**

pfSense is set up through regular wizard. WAN = vSwitch0, LAN = vSwitch1. DHCP server enabled.

NAT (all of these in the port forward tab):

- **General settings**
  NAT reflection for port forwards: Disable
  Automatic outbound NAT for reflection: Disabled
- **RDP to Windows2012R2**
  WAN-interface, proto TCP
  src *, src port *
  Dest address: WAN net, Dest port: 3389
  NAT IP 192.168.174.11, NAT port 3389
- **SSH to Debian Live**
  WAN-interface, proto TCP
  src *, src port *
  Dest address: WAN net, Dest port: 2222
  NAT IP 192.168.174.10, NAT port 22
- **SSH to ESXi host**
  WAN-interface, proto TCP
  src *, src port *
  Dest address: WAN net, Dest port: 22
  NAT IP 192.168.174.12. NAT port 22

**Problem / Question:**
RDP forwarding and SSH to debian works perfectly. I can connect to both from my home network.
However, if I try to connect from my home network to 5.9.100.1:22, my connection fails (timed out).

SSH from home to 5.9.1.1:22 works (I also use SSH tunnels to access vSphere).
SSH from Windows2012R2 VM 192.168.174.11 to ESXi host 192.168.174.12:22 works.

Considering the Debian SSH NAT-rule works, I am quite puzzled towards why the ESXi NAT-rule doesn't.
However, since I am new to both ESXi and pfSense, I am also unsure where to properly diagnose this issue.

**Guesswork**
Given that ESXi still has 'access' to the WAN-port (for now - lockout prevention), skipping pfSense altogether, it might just pick the wrong route to send traffic back to my home network.
If so: is there anything I can do to mitigate this problem with the current setup? *If not* - I might as well just set up the OpenVPN-server on pfSense and get over the port-fowarding issue altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: -- sorry, might be more of a 'Server Fault' topic?

Comment: I bit through the bullet and set up an OpenVPN 'Remote Access' server. Afterwards, removing the management from the WAN-vSwitch, 'solved' the issue at hand. All traffic from ESXi is now routed over the pfSense firewall - it has no other way out. As such, the SSH NAT rule now also works, but is no longer necessary.

Comment: I would agree that this question is better suited for ServerFault, but it looks like a home lab, and if that's the case, they will close it for being "off topic" (very stupid rule IMHO).